# Hibernate 4 - Services and injecting constructor values

Tags: java, hibernate

I am struggling to see how it is possible to override default Services classes provided by Hibernate and to inject specific constructor values. For instance, I am setting `hibernate.jdbc.batch.builder` to the value of my own class, but that implies that the class takes no-param constructor. What if I wanted to supply, let's say,a a default batch size in the constructor? The Service initiatior for BatchBuilder (which is just a factory of batch builders) is able to do that. Do I need to override the default service initiator (if so how?) or is there another way to be able to tailor my own Service implementation?

Answer (score 0):

To create my own Service I used this:

```
public SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration cfg) throws HibernateException {

    Environment.verifyProperties(cfg.getProperties());
    ConfigurationHelper.resolvePlaceHolders(cfg.getProperties());
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder standardServiceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();

    Service myBatchBuilder = new BatchBuilderImpl() {
         // Overwrite default values here
    };
    standardServiceRegistryBuilder.addService(BatchBuilder.class, myBatchBuilder);
    final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry =
            standardServiceRegistryBuilder
                    .applySettings(cfg.getProperties())
                    .build();

    return cfg.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
}
```

However to set batch size at runtime its much easier to use:

```
    BatchBuilderImpl service = (BatchBuilderImpl) getSessionFactory().getSessionFactoryOptions().getServiceRegistry().getService(BatchBuilder.class);
    service.setJdbcBatchSize(batchSize);
```

Note that you have to create a new session so that the new batch size takes effect.